# Does Presidio Framework supports Parallel Processing?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ray, presidio

I am using presidio framework for PII detection along with bert PII models. I tried with ray but, I am not able to achieve parallel processing. Does presidio is compatible for Parallel processing

I tried Ray. When I give multiple sentences for prediction, I am expecting that the prediction process has to be done in parallel and it has to take less time.

Answer (score 0):

If used a a python package, you can utilize the 'BatchAnalyzerEngine', see a sample from the official docs:
https://microsoft.github.io/presidio/samples/python/batch_processing/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35178388)